# printing length of string of Tuples in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

I am a newbie to Scala.
I have a Tuple[Int, String]

```
((1, "alpha"), (2, "beta"), (3, "gamma"), (4, "zeta"), (5, "omega"))
```

For the above list, I want to print all strings where the corresponding length is 4.

Comment: what do you mean by the corresponding length? Is it the length of the string in the tuple? And you've a list of tuple right ?

Comment: Tuple[Int,String] doesn't exist. There you have Tuple5[Tuple2[Int,String],Tuple2[Int,String],Tuple2[Int,String],Tuple2[Int,String],Tuple2[Int,String]].

Answer (score 1):

> > printing length of string of Tuples in Scala

```
val tuples = List((1, "alpha"), (2, "beta"), (3, "gamma"), (4, "zeta"), (5, "omega"))
println(tuples.map(x => (x._2, x._2.length)))
//List((alpha,5), (beta,4), (gamma,5), (zeta,4), (omega,5))
```

> > I want to print all strings where the corresponding length is 4

You can `filter` first and then `print` as

```
val tuples = List((1, "alpha"), (2, "beta"), (3, "gamma"), (4, "zeta"), (5, "omega"))
tuples.filter(_._2.length == 4).foreach(x => println(x._2))
```

it should print

```
beta
zeta
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `Tuple` to `List` and then map and filter as you need:

```
tuple.productIterator.toList
.map{case (a,b) => b.toString}
.filter(_.length==4)
```

Example:

For the given input:

```
 val tuple = ((1, "alpha"), (2, "beta"), (3, "gamma"), (4, "zeta"), (5, "omega"))
tuple: ((Int, String), (Int, String), (Int, String), (Int, String), (Int, String)) = ((1,alpha),(2,beta),(3,gamma),(4,zeta),(5,omega))
```

Output:

```
List[String] = List(beta, zeta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a list of Tuple, and you need all the values with string length equal to 4.

You can do a filter on the list:

```
val filteredList = list.filter(_._2.length == 4)
```

And then iterate over each element to print them:

```
filteredList.foreach(tuple => println(tuple._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to achieve this

```
scala> val x = ((1, "alpha"), (2, "beta"), (3, "gamma"), (4, "zeta"), (5, "omega"))
x: ((Int, String), (Int, String), (Int, String), (Int, String), (Int, String)) = ((1,alpha),(2,beta),(3,gamma),(4,zeta),(5,omega))

scala> val y = x.productIterator.toList.collect{
  case ele : (Int, String) if ele._2.length == 4 => ele._2
}
y: List[String] = List(beta, zeta)
```